Do downvotes in an answer affect asking questions in Mathematics Stack Exchange?
Recently I posted some answers in Mathematics Stack Exchange which are being downvoted. Though many of my answers are upvoted too but some are also downvoted too.
I want to know that will it affect in asking questions in the community? That is can I be blocked from asking questions further?
Please inform me.

You may find information about question blocks in some of the links at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=block

You can get blocked. A general rule is that having on-average well received content in the last month is good enough to not get blocked. And you'll typically get a warning before getting blocked. Not always, but usually.

My impression is that people who operate in good faith don't get banned for very long. But "operating in good faith" would include re-examining your down voted answers and trying not to post other answers that have similar problems. If you can't figure out why those ones are getting down voted, I think there are some chat rooms where you can ask about them.

As follow-up to JonathanZ's comment, I suggest the cured chat room.

No, not usually.
Occasionally, we get people who make poor quality posts consistently. The moderators would step in at that point by warning/suspending them, depending on the severity of past behaviour.

Offending users get flagged automatically, @IITRoorkee.  You will know once you're ever suspended.  Suspensions can last anywhere between 1 to 365 days.  I think extreme cases can even be longer!

A longer (MUCH longer) suspension is discussed at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319634/why-not-perma-ban-instead-of-suspend-an-account-for-275-years#comment1047333_319634
